# Blender OBJ export properties panel missing

Tags: export, panel

Sorry for the newbie question. I have this project where I need to export a mesh in obj format, but I can't see the export properties panel (Export OBJ panel):

[image]

How can I bring it back?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have dragged down all the way. you will see a small **+** icon in bottom of properties panel press it, it will come back.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, tried but nothing happens when pressing the plus button

Comment: @revy Is plus icon visible as in image

Comment: Yes, but for a strange reason I can't click on it! It seems to be a GUI bug